# speed of light observation

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light

I was on a ship at night travelling parallel to the shore watching a lighthouse beam hitting the concrete sea wall. As the beam hit the wall at ninety degrees and continued to rotate I saw what appeared to be the light splitting into its spectrum and streaking away at incredible speed. Was I seeing the actual speed of light as the beam's direction changed?

Comment: Could you describe or post a shematics of the exact geometry of the problem, and how you perceived that splitting (like a rainbow I gess, but oriented in which way?)

Comment: you always see actual speed of light

Comment: @Akash err... what do you mean by that? To me, light looks pretty much instantaneous in most cases...

Comment: yeah i mean that only change in speed og light is not notted by our eyes

Answer (score 2):

Without a more accurate description I can't say for sure but you've probably seen the *difference* in speed of light (in some medium, perhaps the lighthouse glass) between different colors. That's also known as dispersion (in wave physics) or chromatic aberration in optics.